# Check if the number is integer

Tags: r, integer, rounding

I was surprised to learn that R doesn't come with a handy function to check if the number is integer.

```
is.integer(66) # FALSE
```

The [help files warns](http://web.mit.edu/~r/current/lib/R/library/base/html/integer.html):

> `is.integer(x)` does not test if `x`
>   contains integer numbers! For that,
>   use `round`, as in the function
>   `is.wholenumber(x)` in the examples.

The example has this custom function as a "workaround"

```
is.wholenumber <- function(x, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5)  abs(x - round(x)) < tol
is.wholenumber(1) # is TRUE
```

If I would have to write a function to check for integers, assuming I hadn't read the above comments, I would write a function that would go something along the lines of

```
check.integer <- function(x) {
    x == round(x)
}
```

Where would my approach fail? What would be your work around if you were in my hypothetical shoes?

Comment: I would hope that if `round(x)` is implemented properly, the result of applying it to an integer would always be that integer...

Comment: Take a look at the FAQ on R http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f

Comment: > check.integer(9.0)
[1] TRUE
it's not.

Comment: @PengPeng, VitoshKa fixed this in the accepted answer.

Comment: I think there is a confusion about mathematical and computational concepts of integer. The function `is.integer` checks the computational concept, the `check.integer` user function checks the mathematical point of view.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Another alternative is to check the fractional part:

```
x%%1==0
```

or, if you want to check within a certain tolerance:

```
min(abs(c(x%%1, x%%1-1))) < tol
```

Comment: does the tolerance-checking suggestion really work??  `x <- 5-1e-8; x%%1` gives 0.9999999 (which would imply if `tol==1e-5` for example) that `x` is **not** an integer.

Comment: @BenBolker Good catch, it works for positive perturbations I think. I've changed it to an alternative solution should work.

Comment: @James, I think it should be `min(abs(c(x%%1, x%%1-1))) < tol` instead of `abs(min(x%%1, x%%1-1)) < tol` otherwise, you'll get `FALSE` for any integer...

Comment: What's wrong with `as.integer(x) == x`? It will not reject 3 or 3.0 like `is.integer(x)` would, and it will catch 3.1.

Answer (score 40):

Here's a solution using simpler functions and no hacks:

```
all.equal(a, as.integer(a))
```

What's more, you can test a whole vector at once, if you wish.  Here's a function:

```
testInteger <- function(x){
  test <- all.equal(x, as.integer(x), check.attributes = FALSE)
  if(test == TRUE){ return(TRUE) }
  else { return(FALSE) }
}
```

You can change it to use `*apply` in the case of vectors, matrices, etc.

Comment: The last `if` `else` could be done with simply `isTRUE(test)`. Indeed that is all you need to replace the `if` `else` clause and the `return` statements as R automatically returns the result of the last evaluation.

Comment: ``testInteger(1.0000001)``
[1] FALSE

``testInteger(1.00000001)``
[1] TRUE

Comment: `all(a == as.integer(a))` gets around this problem!'

Comment: This is not working properly! Check out the following counter-example: frac_test <- 1/(1-0.98), all.equal(frac_test, as.integer(frac_test)), isTRUE(all.equal(frac_test, as.integer(frac_test)))

Answer (score 11):

Reading the R language documentation, `as.integer` has more to do with how the number is stored than if it is practically equivalent to an integer. `is.integer` tests if the number is declared as an integer.  You can declare an integer by putting a `L` after it.

```
> is.integer(66L)
[1] TRUE
> is.integer(66)
[1] FALSE
```

Also functions like `round` will return a declared integer, which is what you are doing with `x==round(x)`.  The problem with this approach is what you consider to be practically an integer.  The example uses less precision for testing equivalence.

```
> is.wholenumber(1+2^-50)
[1] TRUE
> check.integer(1+2^-50)
[1] FALSE
```

So depending on your application you could get into trouble that way.

Comment: The second line says "as.integer tests if the number is declared as an integer." but I am pretty sure you meant "is.integer". It is only a one character edit so I couldn't easily change it.

Answer (score 11):

Here is one, apparently reliable way:

```
check.integer <- function(N){
    !grepl("[^[:digit:]]", format(N,  digits = 20, scientific = FALSE))
}

check.integer(3243)
#TRUE
check.integer(3243.34)
#FALSE
check.integer("sdfds")
#FALSE
```

This solution also allows for integers in scientific notation:

```
> check.integer(222e3)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This doesn't look very reliable to me: `check.integer(1e4)` is TRUE, while `check.integer(1e5)` is FALSE.

Comment: -1 This is worse than `is.wholenumber`, or any of the other solutions provided in other answers. These shouldn't be different: `check.integer(1e22); check.integer(1e23)`. You can obviously change the regex to fix this, but this approach is dreadful. (Comment comes from attribution in the installr package.)

Comment: @Joshua, Your comment is completely misleading for three reasons. First, 1e22 in your example cannot be represented accurately, and all non-regexp based solutions will fail. For example the now accepted solution (1e20+1.1)%%1 will give you 0 with a warning! Second, does this string represent an integer "1313213121313232321123213"? If you think it does, then my solution is the only one which works at all!

Comment: And finally, how do you think R parser understands that you entered an integer if not by regexp-type matching? From what you say, R parser is "dreadful". If I would implement a complete specification of an integer in my reg-exp it will never fail!

Comment: check.Integer(1.000001)
[1] FALSE
check.Integer(1.0000001)
[1] TRUE

Comment: It does here. I just checked again. I can't explain it. Here a screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/xrbx1dlen/

Comment: @PatrickT, I see. It's the default digit's argument. use `format(40, scientific = FALSE, digits = 20)` instead. I have updated the answer. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: @VitoshKa, much better, but there's a break at 15 digits, not 20 - is that expected? ``check.integer(1.000000000000001)``
[1] FALSE
``check.integer(1.0000000000000001)``
[1] TRUE

Comment: @PatrickT You are in the realm of machine dependent rounding errors.  In that respect my solution is the same as the accepted one `1.0000000000000001 == 1L [1] TRUE`. But my solution is better if you already get a number in string form `check.integer("1000000000000000000000000000000000001") [1] TRUE`

Comment: @VitoshKa, couldn't that problem be avoided if you convert the number to a character and look for the presence of non-zero digits after the decimal dot marker? I assumed that was the point of your choice of ``grepl``?

Comment: @PatrickT. That's precisely what `format` does. It converts to character.

Comment: @VitoshKa, thanks! Ah got it: ``?print.default`` __Note that for large values of digits, currently for digits >= 16, the calculation of the number of significant digits will depend on the platform's internal (C library) implementation of sprintf() functionality. __

Comment: @VitoshKa loved your answer! Although there is one point that you missed, negative numbers without decimal points are also integer ;) I modified your code accordingly.

Comment: @MehradMahmoudian How did you cope with negative numbers?

Answer (score 9):

It appears that you do not see the need to incorporate some error tolerance. It would not be needed if all integers came entered as integers, however sometimes they come as a result of arithmetic operations that loose some precision. For example:

```
> 2/49*49
[1] 2
> check.integer(2/49*49)
[1] FALSE 
> is.wholenumber(2/49*49)
[1] TRUE
```

Note that this is not R's weakness, all computer software have some limits of precision.

Comment: just in case some people don't quite get what happened here... if you enter as.integer(2/49*49) you get 1 !!  

[BTW, it is ever so frustrating that R doesn't present the result of the initial calculation as 2.0 to represent that the value has some decimal component) see... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535021/whats-the-biggest-r-gotcha-youve-run-across/3398868#3398868

Answer (score 6):

From `Hmisc::spss.get`:

```
all(floor(x) == x, na.rm = TRUE)
```

much safer option, IMHO, since it "bypasses" the machine precision issue. If you try `is.integer(floor(1))`, you'll get `FALSE`. BTW, your integer will not be saved as integer if it's bigger than `.Machine$integer.max` value, which is, by default 2147483647, so either change the `integer.max` value, or do the alternative checks...

Comment: if `x <- sqrt(2)^2`, then `all(floor(x) == x, na.rm = TRUE)` return `FALSE`

Answer (score 6):

you can use simple if condition like:

```
if(round(var) != var)­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­
```

Answer (score 1):

In R, whether a number is numeric or integer can be determined by class function. Generally all numbers are stored as numeric and to explicitly define a number as integer we need to specify 'L' after the number.

Example:

> x <- 1
>
> class(x)

[1] "numeric"

> x <- 1L
>
> class(x)

[1] "integer"

I hope this is what was needed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer not to write your own function, try [`check.integer`](https://rdrr.io/cran/installr/man/check.integer.html) from package **installr**. Currently [it uses](https://github.com/talgalili/installr/blob/2d55bd05dbdcb6711fc84900ca9d5871a9eb0858/R/install.R#L338) VitoshKa's answer.

Also try [`check.numeric(v, only.integer=TRUE)`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/varhandle/versions/2.0.3/topics/check.numeric) from package **varhandle**, which has the benefit of being vectorized.

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATE] ==============================================================

Respect to the [OLD] answer here below, I have discovered that it worked because I have put all the numbers in a single atomic vector; one of them was a character, so every one become characters.

If we use a list (hence, coercion does not happen) all the test pass correctly but one: `1/(1 - 0.98)`, which remains a `numeric`. This because the `tol` parameter is by default `100 * .Machine$double.eps` and that number is far from `50` little less than the double of that. So, basically, for this kind of numbers, we *have* to decide our tolerance!

So if you want all test became `TRUE`, you can `assertive::is_whole_number(x, tol = 200 * .Machine$double.eps)`

Anyway, I confirm that IMO assertive remains the best solution.

Here below a reprex for this [UPDATE].

```r
expect_trues_c <- c(
  cl = sqrt(2)^2,
  pp = 9.0,
  t = 1 / (1 - 0.98),
  ar0 = 66L,
  ar1 = 66,
  ar2 = 1 + 2^-50,
  v = 222e3,
  w1 = 1e4,
  w2 = 1e5,
  v2 = "1000000000000000000000000000000000001",
  an = 2 / 49 * 49,
  ju1 = 1e22,
  ju2 = 1e24,
  al = floor(1),
  v5 = 1.0000000000000001 # this is under machine precision!
)

str(expect_trues_c)
#>  Named chr [1:15] "2" "9" "50" "66" "66" "1" "222000" "10000" "1e+05" ...
#>  - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:15] "cl" "pp" "t" "ar0" ...
assertive::is_whole_number(expect_trues_c)
#> Warning: Coercing expect_trues_c to class 'numeric'.
#>                      2                      9                     50 
#>                   TRUE                   TRUE                   TRUE 
#>                     66                     66                      1 
#>                   TRUE                   TRUE                   TRUE 
#>                 222000                  10000                 100000 
#>                   TRUE                   TRUE                   TRUE 
#>                  1e+36                      2                  1e+22 
#>                   TRUE                   TRUE                   TRUE 
#> 9.9999999999999998e+23                      1                      1 
#>                   TRUE                   TRUE                   TRUE



expect_trues_l <- list(
  cl = sqrt(2)^2,
  pp = 9.0,
  t = 1 / (1 - 0.98),
  ar0 = 66L,
  ar1 = 66,
  ar2 = 1 + 2^-50,
  v = 222e3,
  w1 = 1e4,
  w2 = 1e5,
  v2 = "1000000000000000000000000000000000001",
  an = 2 / 49 * 49,
  ju1 = 1e22,
  ju2 = 1e24,
  al = floor(1),
  v5 = 1.0000000000000001 # this is under machine precision!
)

str(expect_trues_l)
#> List of 15
#>  $ cl : num 2
#>  $ pp : num 9
#>  $ t  : num 50
#>  $ ar0: int 66
#>  $ ar1: num 66
#>  $ ar2: num 1
#>  $ v  : num 222000
#>  $ w1 : num 10000
#>  $ w2 : num 1e+05
#>  $ v2 : chr "1000000000000000000000000000000000001"
#>  $ an : num 2
#>  $ ju1: num 1e+22
#>  $ ju2: num 1e+24
#>  $ al : num 1
#>  $ v5 : num 1
assertive::is_whole_number(expect_trues_l)
#> Warning: Coercing expect_trues_l to class 'numeric'.
#> There was 1 failure:
#>   Position              Value      Cause
#> 1        3 49.999999999999957 fractional
assertive::is_whole_number(expect_trues_l, tol = 200 * .Machine$double.eps)
#> Warning: Coercing expect_trues_l to class 'numeric'.
#>     2.0000000000000004                      9     49.999999999999957 
#>                   TRUE                   TRUE                   TRUE 
#>                     66                     66     1.0000000000000009 
#>                   TRUE                   TRUE                   TRUE 
#>                 222000                  10000                 100000 
#>                   TRUE                   TRUE                   TRUE 
#>                  1e+36     1.9999999999999998                  1e+22 
#>                   TRUE                   TRUE                   TRUE 
#> 9.9999999999999998e+23                      1                      1 
#>                   TRUE                   TRUE                   TRUE



expect_falses <- list(
  bb = 5 - 1e-8,
  pt1 = 1.0000001,
  pt2 = 1.00000001,
  v3 = 3243.34,
  v4 = "sdfds"
)

str(expect_falses)
#> List of 5
#>  $ bb : num 5
#>  $ pt1: num 1
#>  $ pt2: num 1
#>  $ v3 : num 3243
#>  $ v4 : chr "sdfds"
assertive::is_whole_number(expect_falses)
#> Warning: Coercing expect_falses to class 'numeric'.
#> Warning in as.this_class(x): NAs introduced by coercion
#> There were 5 failures:
#>   Position              Value      Cause
#> 1        1 4.9999999900000001 fractional
#> 2        2 1.0000001000000001 fractional
#> 3        3 1.0000000099999999 fractional
#> 4        4 3243.3400000000001 fractional
#> 5        5               <NA>    missing
assertive::is_whole_number(expect_falses, tol = 200 * .Machine$double.eps)
#> Warning: Coercing expect_falses to class 'numeric'.

#> Warning: NAs introduced by coercion
#> There were 5 failures:
#>   Position              Value      Cause
#> 1        1 4.9999999900000001 fractional
#> 2        2 1.0000001000000001 fractional
#> 3        3 1.0000000099999999 fractional
#> 4        4 3243.3400000000001 fractional
#> 5        5               <NA>    missing
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

[OLD] =================================================================

IMO the best solution comes from the `assertive` package (which, for the moment, solve all positive and negative examples in this thread):

```r
are_all_whole_numbers <- function(x) {
  all(assertive::is_whole_number(x), na.rm = TRUE)
}

are_all_whole_numbers(c(
  cl = sqrt(2)^2,
  pp = 9.0,
  t = 1 / (1 - 0.98),
  ar0 = 66L,
  ar1 = 66,
  ar2 = 1 + 2^-50,
  v = 222e3,
  w1 = 1e4,
  w2 = 1e5,
  v2 = "1000000000000000000000000000000000001",
  an = 2 / 49 * 49,
  ju1 = 1e22,
  ju2 = 1e24,
  al = floor(1),
  v5 = 1.0000000000000001 # difference is under machine precision!
))
#> Warning: Coercing x to class 'numeric'.
#> [1] TRUE

are_all_not_whole_numbers <- function(x) {
  all(!assertive::is_whole_number(x), na.rm = TRUE)
}

are_all_not_whole_numbers(c(
  bb = 5 - 1e-8,
  pt1 = 1.0000001,
  pt2 = 1.00000001,
  v3 = 3243.34,
  v4 = "sdfds"
))
#> Warning: Coercing x to class 'numeric'.
#> Warning in as.this_class(x): NAs introduced by coercion
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt at a solution using Rcpp for the case when you want to check that all numbers are whole numbers.

**Edit**: Updated the C++ function.

#### Rcpp function

```r
library(bench)
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('SEXP cpp_is_whole_num(SEXP x, SEXP tol, bool na_rm = true) {
  R_xlen_t n = Rf_xlength(x);
  int tol_len = Rf_length(tol);
  if (tol_len > 1){
    Rcpp::stop("tol must be of length <= 1");
  }
  if (tol_len == 0){
    n = 0;
  }
  bool is_whole;
  double adiff;
  R_xlen_t n_na = 0;
  bool is_na;
  SEXP out = PROTECT(Rf_allocVector(LGLSXP, 1));
  int *p_out = INTEGER(out);
  p_out[0] = false;
  switch ( TYPEOF(x) ){
  case LGLSXP:
  case INTSXP: {
    p_out[0] = true;
    break;
  }
  case REALSXP: {
    // Re-initialise so that we can break when we find non-whole num
    p_out[0] = true;
    double *p_x = REAL(x);
    double *p_t = REAL(tol);
    for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      adiff = std::fabs(p_x[i] - std::round(p_x[i]));
      is_whole = (adiff < p_t[0]);
      is_na = !(p_x[i] == p_x[i]);
      n_na += is_na;
      if (!is_whole && !is_na){
        p_out[0] = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!na_rm && n_na > 0){
      p_out[0] = NA_LOGICAL;
      break;
    }
    break;
  }
  }
  UNPROTECT(1);
  return out;
}')
```

#### Benchmark

```
x1 <- c(1:10^7, 0.01)
x2 <- c(0.01, 1:10^7)

# Non-integers at the end of the vector

mark(james = all(x1%%1==0),
     iterator = isTRUE(all.equal(x1, as.integer(x1))),
     me = cpp_is_whole_num(x1, sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)))
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is
#> disabled.
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 james       306.4ms    318ms      3.15  114.44MB     3.15
#> 2 iterator    271.2ms    273ms      3.66  305.46MB     5.50
#> 3 me           34.3ms     38ms     24.0     2.49KB     0

# Non-integers at the start of the vector

mark(james = all(x2%%1==0),
     iterator = isTRUE(all.equal(x2, as.integer(x2))),
     me = cpp_is_whole_num(x2, sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)))
#> Warning: Some expressions had a GC in every iteration; so filtering is
#> disabled.
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 james       242.1ms  264.8ms      3.78  114.44MB     1.89
#> 2 iterator    215.5ms  266.4ms      3.71  305.18MB     7.42
#> 3 me            1.7µs    2.8µs 266295.      2.49KB     0

# R wrapper to account for non-numeric classes and coercion
is_whole_number <- function(x, tol = sqrt(.Machine$double.eps), na.rm = TRUE){
  is.numeric(x) && cpp_is_whole_num(x, tol = as.double(tol), na_rm = na.rm)
}

## NA handling
x <- c(1, NA)
y <- c(1.5, NA)

is_whole_number(x, na.rm = F)
#> [1] NA
is_whole_number(y, na.rm = F)
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Once can also use `dplyr::near`:

```
library(dplyr)

near(a, as.integer(a))
```

It applies to any vector `a`, and has an optional tolerance parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For a vector `m`, `m[round(m) != m]` will return the indices of values in the vector that are not integers.

Answer (score -5):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish. But here are some thoughts:

1. Convert to integer:

`num = as.integer(123.2342)`


2. Check if a variable is an integer:


`is.integer(num)

typeof(num)=="integer"`

Comment: I'm just making sure the users enters an appropriate number - we're talking about the number of "subjects", which can be only an integer.