# How do I convert a `raw` into a vector of integers in R?

Tags: r

I need to pass a raw back to Java via JRI, but it doesn't support raws, only various other vector types (such as integers).  How do I convert a raw (vector of bytes) into a vector of integers?

I tried passing the data back as a vector of strings, but that breaks because JRI doesn't decode the string properly (eg '\x89' gets discarded as "").

Would also be nice if it were more efficient (unboxed). `as.integer` does not work - it doesn't return the byte values of the characters in the array, not to mention the fact that rawToChar produces "" for nuls.

Answer (score 6):

Taking this a stage further, you can readBin directly from a raw vector.  So we can:

```
> raw
[1] 2b 97 53 eb 86 b9 4a c6 6c ca 40 80 06 94 bc 08 3a fb bc f4
> readBin(raw, what='integer', n=length(raw)/4)
[1]  -346843349  -968181370 -2143237524   146576390  -188941510
```

Answer (score 3):

This question is pretty old, but for those who (like myself) came across this while searching for an answer: as.integer(raw.vec) works well.

```
f <- file("/tmp/a.out", "rb")
seek(f, 0, "end")
f.size <- seek(f, NA, "start")
seek(f, 0, "start")
raw.vec <- readBin(f, 'raw', f.size, 1, signed=FALSE)
close(f)
bytes <- as.integer(raw.vec)
```

Answer (score 2):

See documentation for `rawToChar`:

> rawToChar converts raw bytes either to a single character string or a
>   character vector of single bytes (with "" for 0).

Of course, once you manage to get it to `character`, you can easily convert it to integer via `as.integer` method, but be [cautious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476782/how-to-check-if-the-number-is-integer).

Comment: I should've mentioned that I'm currently passing the data back as a vector of strings (where each string contains just 0 or 1 chars) - I was looking for something more efficient (unboxed). `as.integer` does not work - it doesn't return the byte values of the characters in the array, not to mention the fact that rawToChar produces "" for nuls.