# Convert a number to character and format

Tags: r

I've made this function which will convert any 9 or less to a word and will also format large numbers by inserting a comma:

```
library(english); library(stringr)

reportNumber <- function (number) {
  ifelse(number > 9, str_trim(format(number, big.mark= ",", scientific = F)), as.character(english(number)))
}
```

The function works like this:

```
reportNumber(c(0, 9, 10, 100, 1000, 10000))

# [1] "zero"   "nine"   "10"     "100"    "1,000"  "10,000"
```

But if the number has a decimal point, the function errors:

```
reportNumber(c(0.1, 9.1, 10.1, 100.1, 1000.1, 10000.1))
```

I need to make the function test whether a number has a decimal point, and if true, then just print the number unformatted. So the output should simply be:

```
c(0.1, 9.1, 10.1, 100.1, 1000.1, 10000.1)

# [1]     0.1     9.1    10.1   100.1  1000.1 10000.1
```

Comment: `grepl(".", number), ...)` may work for that problem.  Or possibly `is.double`

Comment: Richard's basic idea is fine, but `.` is a special character in regex. You probably would need to specify `fixed = TRUE` in `grepl`.

Comment: Thanks @joran.  You'd also want to remove the `, ...)` since I forgot to cut that out when I edited the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question essentially boils down to checking if a number is an integer, which has been addressed [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476782/how-to-check-if-the-number-is-integer) on SO. You might try:

```
reportNumber <- function (number) {
  ifelse(number %% 1 != 0, as.character(number),
         ifelse(number > 9,
                str_trim(format(number, big.mark= ",", scientific = F)),
                as.character(english(number))))
}
reportNumber(c(0, 9, 10, 100, 1000, 10000))
# [1] "zero"   "nine"   "10"     "100"    "1,000"  "10,000"
reportNumber(c(0.1, 9.1, 10.1, 100.1, 1000.1, 10000.1))
# [1] "0.1"     "9.1"     "10.1"    "100.1"   "1000.1"  "10000.1"
```