# In R, why does is.integer(1) return FALSE?

Tags: r, types, integer, numeric, type-conversion

In R, `is.integer(1)` returns FALSE and `class(1)` returns "numeric" while `is.integer(1:1)` returns TRUE and `class(1:1)` returns "integer".  Why does not `is.integer(1)` return TRUE?

Comparing the printed values to the output of class() or typeof() leads to counter intuitive results. E.g.

```
x1=seq(from=1, to=5, by=1) 
x2=1:5
x1 
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 
x2 
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 
class(x1) 
[1] "numeric" 
class(x2)
[1] "integer"
```

To determine if x1 contains integer values I need to use `all(as.integer(x1)==x1)`.  Is there an easier way?

`class()` can return an array, e.g. an ordered factor.  Shouldn't `class(1)` return c("numeric", "integer")?

Comment: Numbers are treated as `numeric` by default in R. Try `x <- 1L` to force an `integer`.

Comment: See, also, the "Note" and the "Examples" in `?is.integer`

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476782/how-to-check-if-the-number-is-integer , but you're asking two questions here: (1) "is there an easier way to test for integer values"? (dupe of previous) and (2) "shouldn't `class(1)` return `c("numeric","integer")`?"  (Partly addressed by @jlhoward's now-deleted answer)

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully this helps clear things up a bit.  Your example doesn't necessarily 
tell the whole truth.  In fact, the vector type returned from `seq` depends
on which arguments you use.  Here's a look at the example set-ups from 
`?seq`.

```
seqList <- list(
    fromto = seq(from = 1, to = 5),
    fromtoby = seq(from = 1, to = 5, by = 1),
    fromtolengthout = seq(from = 1, to = 5, length.out = 5),
    alongwith = seq(along.with = 5),
    from = seq(from = 1),
    lengthout = seq(length.out = 5),
    binary = 1:5
)
```

With the result, we can see that when we use the `by` argument (as you did),
the result is not of integer type.  The type of result is changed to numeric once argument checking occurs (I think, correct me if I'm wrong).

```
str(seqList)
# List of 7
#  $ fromto         : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#  $ fromtoby       : num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#  $ fromtolengthout: num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#  $ alongwith      : int 1
#  $ from           : int 1
#  $ lengthout      : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
#  $ binary         : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
```

`seq` is a generic function that dispatches to different methods based on the supplied arguments.  It's all explained in `?seq`.  It's worth a read.  There are also `seq.int`, `seq_len`, and `seq_along` which are also different from `seq`. Now in reference to your question

> To determine if x1 contains integer values I need to use `all(as.integer(x1)==x1)`. Is there an easier way?

That check might cause some issues, as factors are also integers

```
f <- factor(letters[1:5])
x <- 1:5
f == x
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
as.integer(f) == x
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

I'd go with `inherits` or `typeof`. The first returns a logical, which would work nicely in `if` statements.  And `typeof` returns a character string of the vector type.

```
look <- function(x) {
    c(class = class(x), typeof = typeof(x), 
      mode = mode(x), inherits = inherits(x, "integer"))
}
noquote(do.call(rbind, lapply(seqList, look)))
#                 class   typeof  mode    inherits
# fromto          integer integer numeric TRUE    
# fromtoby        numeric double  numeric FALSE   
# fromtolengthout numeric double  numeric FALSE   
# alongwith       integer integer numeric TRUE    
# from            integer integer numeric TRUE    
# lengthout       integer integer numeric TRUE    
# binary          integer integer numeric TRUE
```

Reading the help files is very informative. I'm definitely not an expert on this stuff, so if I've gotten anything wrong here, please let me know.  Here's something more to stimulate the curiosity:

```
is.integer(1)
# [1] FALSE
is.integer(1L)
# [1] TRUE
```