# testing for an integer square root in R

Tags: r, integer-division, sqrt

How can I test if the square root of a number is an integer using R?

The following all evaluate to `FALSE`.

```
is.integer( sqrt(25) )
is.integer( sqrt(25L) )
```

Comment: sorry I hadn't seen this question, my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a work around, but I'm not sure if it's efficient or even robust to using more exotic numbers.

```
25 %% sqrt(25) == 0
```

Evaluates to `TRUE`.

Perhaps a better way of doing this would be:

```
sqrt(25) %% 1 == 0
```

Which also evaluates to `TRUE`. Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3477158/1328355).

Comment: You should check `?is.integer`, particularly the function `is.wholenumber` defined in the "Examples" section.

Comment: if your square root is not an integer then you would be doing integer dvision with non integer, which is not a good idea and if it is an integer, the square root definition is that sqrt(k)*sqrt(k)==k so it will always be TRUE. Sorry but I have to downvote this very wrong "answer". @Pascal, why did you delete your answer?

Comment: thanks @Pascal I've looked at the `is.wholenumber` example but I didn't think that that was very clear or exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @CathG thanks, I don't really agree with you, from the R documentation `%% and x %/% y can be used for non-integer y, e.g. 1 %/% 0.2,`. However, I have updated my answer with an alternative which uses 1.

Comment: @CathG I don't understand the statement that "a number will always be 0 modulo to its square root". I can only see that being true when the result is an integer. `3 %% sqrt(3)` is not 0, and if a square root isn't an integer it can't give a modulo 0 for its square since it needs to be multiplied by another non-integer (i.e. will have a remainder). Am I being silly?

Comment: right, good point, I am "stupidely" thinking of integer multiplication with integers, I have a mathematical background and it seems my head doesn't want to imagine we can do "%%" with non integers............ ;-)

Comment: @bquast, yes they can "but the results are subject to representation error" and it's mathematically wrong... also, try `sqrt(8+1/3+1/3+1/3) %% 1 == 0` or `(8+1/3+1/3+1/3)%%sqrt(8+1/3+1/3+1/3)`