# getting a python while statement using != to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, syntax-error

So i have a program called lonesum(a,b,c) that needs to add the 3 numbers entered together only if they are input once. so lonesum(1,2,3) would return 6 but lonesum(1,1,3) would return 3. I have that part. What i need help with is getting a statement to work that will return an error if the user enters anything that isn't an integer i.e. lonesum(.5,2,3) will return error. so far i have this while statement which i thought would work but doesn't,:

```
while (a,b,c) != int:
     print("Error")
     return None
while a==b==c:
    return 0
while a==b:
    return c
while b==c:
    return a
while a==c:
    return b
while a!=b!=c:
    sum1=(a+b+c)
    return sum1
```

(That is the rest of my code, that is the part that works)

My problem is the != doesn't work and I'm not sure what to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using `(a,b,c) != int:`? What do you think this condition examines?

Comment: the (a,b,c) is the input from when you run the lonesum(a,b,c) function. I was hoping that putting while (a,b,c), the input, != int, (an integer) that  it would print error and return none.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't the print missing a double quote?

Comment: A `while` that always returns on the first iteration is an `if`

Comment: `(a,b,c)` is creating a tuple. And the comparison is just wrong, even something like `1 == int` will return `False`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if the number is integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476782/check-if-the-number-is-integer)

Comment: i understand that now, but i entered it in that way so that i could better describe what i need to do. I need to have the first part return error if the user enters a non-integer. I am literally half way through my first course ever in python and computer science in general. So i don't know everything yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if not all(type(v) is int for v in (a, b, c)):
    print("Error!")
    return None
```

What you want to check is if each value in (a, b, c) is of integer type. So you must check each value, not the tuple itself.

The builtin function `all` iterates over something iterable and returns true if all of the values are true. I've created a generator expression that iterates over the tuple (a, b, c), comparing the type of each value to `int`. `all` iterates over that generator expression. So if all of the values in (a, b, c) have type `int`, it returns `True`.

Comment: That works! thank you! If i can ask, do you think you could explain why it works so that i can understand it more? I'm still in the process of learning python and as nice as my professor is, she isn't very good at explaing things.

Comment: @ConorHastings: Read the docs for [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and the [generator expression tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions); that covers both of the components here.

Comment: Side-note: Specific type checking is usually a bad idea, since it makes your code not work with anything but `int`, even if it's logically integer data (e.g. `numpy` integer types, `gmpy2.mpz`, `long` on Python 2, etc.). That's why duck typing is encouraged, or failing that, checking a more generic abstract type with `isinstance`, e.g. in this case, `all(isinstance(v, numbers.Integral) for v in (a, b, c))`.

Comment: @ConorHastings: I applaud you for asking for a better explanation. It's encouraging that you're interested in learning, not just getting your assignment done. And it keeps me honest -- I got a bit lazy.

Comment: You should probably also look at the Python Tutorial located at the main Python site, @ConorHastings. [Here's a link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) for that. After that try looking through Q&A's here on StackOverflow, there's a **ton** of amazing content by great people.

Comment: Thank you! I will be sure to check it out!

Answer (score 2):

If you want the sum of all numbers that appear exactly once, there are more succinct ways to do it. Count them all, sum the ones that appear once:

```
from collections import Counter

def lonesum(a, b, c):
    counts = Counter((a, b, c))
    return sum(v for v, cnt in counts.items() if cnt == 1)
```

This implicitly raises an error if a non-numeric value is passed as an argument when it tries to sum them; if you want to `print` an error instead of propagating the exception, make it:

```
def lonesum(a, b, c):
    try:
        counts = Counter((a, b, c))
        return sum(v for v, cnt in counts.items() if cnt == 1)
    except TypeError:
        print("Error!")
        return None
```

Comment: I know what i have is not ideal. But like i said, we haven't even learned how to do stuff like that yet.