# How to mark all integer values to "-1" in R Studio?

Tags: r, rscript

What is equivalent SQL server isnumeric function in  R studio. I am trying to migrate one of SQL logic to r studio and i have column where it holds both Char values and Int values, now i want take only int values and update them as -1 in R data.table. Please help me to solve the problem.

I have attached results as image, column "A" values are current values and i am expecting have the values like column B.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think I have an answer for you below, but for the next time please ask with [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1422451) code/data per the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [`r`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) tag description. Please only use screenshots to display something inherently visual and nontabular like a plot or a GUI menu.

Comment: `ifelse(is.na(as.integer(x)), x, -1)`, where `x` is your column data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have fix this issue by following below steps.

1. captured all numeric values to separate data table by using below script
   CustomDerivedL2AMID <- (subset(DimCombinedEnduser$DRVDEUL2AMID, grepl('^\d+$',DimCombinedEnduser$DRVDEUL2AMID)))
   library(data.table)
   HandleDerivedL2AMID <-data.table(CustomDerivedL2AMID)
2. match the HandleDerivedL2AMID table results with original data table and replaced all values to -1.
   DCE$DRVDEUL2AMID <- replace(DCE$DRVDEUL2AMID,DCE$DRVDEUL2AMID %in% HandleDerivedL2AMID$CustomDerivedL2AMID,'-1')

now i see only character values. no more numeric values with data set under DRVDEUL2AMID.

Answer (score 1):

There are also data type tools in R (as in SQL and other languages) such as `is.numeric()` and `is.integer()` in R. Normally these return boolean values, but you could use `sub` or `gsub()` to make it `-1`:

```
example <- list(123, 321, "not numeric", as.Date("2018/01/01"))

gsub(T, -1, sapply(example, is.numeric))
```

> ```
> [1] "-1" "-1" "FALSE"   "FALSE"
> ```

Also, note that in R `numeric` is different from `integer`.

```
example <- list(as.integer(123), 321, "not numeric", as.Date("2018/01/01"))
example[sapply(example, is.integer)] <- -1
example
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] -1
>
> [[2]]
> [1] 321
>
> [[3]]
> [1] "not numeric"
>
> [[4]]
> [1] "2018-01-01"
> ```

You can convert them back and forth with `as.numeric()` and `as.integer()`. Also, note that in R data types in this sense are referred to as the class or classes of the data, whereas the type in R refers to the storage or R internal data type.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately i am not able to fix the issue. when i use following statement "sub(T, -1, sapply(DimCombinedEnduser$DRVDEUL2AMID, is.numeric))" it's giving "FALSE" as results set that mean it's considering all integer values as chars. if i convert the column as numeric it's updating all values as "-1" instead of Integer values. i can share some sample records in offline.

Comment: same statement working fine when hard code the values and parse it, but when i run same statement through column it's not working. is there anything i need to check it explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you're specifically interested in integers, then the question above is a duplicate of the following:
[Check if the number is integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476782/check-if-the-number-is-integer)

Your if condition would be something like x == round(x, 0). This will be TRUE if values are integers, but not double or other non-numeric classes.