# correctly subset a list to replace element values

Tags: r, list

**Context:**
I have a list of data frames, each containing with different dimensions and column data types. My final objective is to create a named vector containing the column name and data type, that I can use to explicitly assign field types for writing a table into a database - the `field.types` argument in `DBI::dbWriteTable()`

**Approach:**
My current method is to extract the data type of the columns in the list using `class`, modifying it so that so I can use it as the named vector to in the `field.types` argument. I need to assess whether the data are truly integer values and I wrote a function to do that based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476782/check-if-the-number-is-integer).

**Objective:**
I want to use the list output from my own function to identify and modify the data type in the named vector that are truly integer values.

**Problem:**
I want to replace the elements in the list `list_class` based on another list `list_int` with logical vectors. I can do this simple replacement/assignment for single data frame but I run into subset issues when using a list of data frames. I've included a reproducible example and some attempts at this below.

```
library(purrr)

list_df <- list(
  df1 = data.frame(v1 = seq(1,10,2),
                   v2 = seq(1,5,1),
                   v3 = seq(1,10,length.out = 5)),
  df2 = data.frame(v2 = c(seq(1,5), NA),
                   v3 = seq(2,7,1),
                   v4 = rep(pi,6)),
  df3 = data.frame(v3 = seq(1,2,length.out = 5),
                   v4 = sample(letters,5),
                   v5 = seq(1,10,2),
                   v6 = seq(1,5,1))
  )

list_class <- map(list_df, ~map_chr(., class)) #named vector

check_int <- function(v) { #check if truly integer value
  if (!is.numeric(v)) FALSE
  else all((v%%1 == 0)[!is.na(v%%1 == 0)])
}

list_int <- map(list_df, ~map_lgl(., ~check_int(.)))
```

For a single data frame below works

```
list_class[[1]][list_int[[1]]] <- "newdatatype"
```

And I am able to extract the subset that I want from the list using base `Map`.

```
Map('[', list_class, list_int)
```

Looking for insight to how put all these pieces together or if my approach is completely off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `for` loop should work, but you could also use `map2` if you wanted a `purrr` solution.

for Loop:

```
for(i in seq_along(list_class))
  list_class[[i]][list_int[[i]]] <- "newdatatype"
```

purrr:

```
map2(list_class, list_int, ~{.x[.y] <- 'newdatatype'; .x})
```

output:

```
# $df1
#            v1            v2            v3 
# "newdatatype" "newdatatype"     "numeric" 
# 
# $df2
#            v2            v3            v4 
# "newdatatype" "newdatatype"     "numeric" 
# 
# $df3
#            v3            v4            v5            v6 
#     "numeric"      "factor" "newdatatype" "newdatatype"
```

Comment: I completely forgot about `map2`, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3):

You can do...

```
Map(replace, list_class, list_int, "newdatatatype")
# or
Map(function(x, p) replace(x, p, "newdatatatype"), list_class, list_int)
```

This creates a new object rather than modifying `list_class`, but you're using the tidyverse and so should not be interested in modifying input anyways, I guess. If you really want to, there's...

```
library(magrittr)
list_class %<>% Map(
  f = function(x, p) replace(x, p, "newdatatatype"), 
  p = list_int
)
```

Side note: If you look at the code in `replace`, you'll see it's just a wrapper / convenience function for what Ryan's code does more directly.

Comment: thanks for the explanation and the note. I wasn't restricted to the tidyverse but this is good to learn the different functions that exist in `base` R

Comment: @EJJ Ok cool. Fyi, you can use `map2(list_class, list_int, ~replace(.x, .y, "newdatatype"))`. I didn't add it here because I'm not familiar enough with purrr's `~` stuff ... just adapted it by substitution into Ryan's answer.

Comment: okay, thanks. I've never used `replace` before so it's something I'll need to read up on.