# R- identify columns with integers

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to be able to identify columns in a dataframe (eg  cols `am` and `vs` in `mtcars` ) that contain integers and convert them to factors.

Important note: In the dataset, columns that do contain integers, are encoded as numeric (so `is.integer` would not work)..

Is there a solution with tidyverse?
Thank you!

**EDIT:**
I found the solution in this post: [check if all values in data.frame columns are integers to subset dummy variables aka are all values in a column TRUE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60549597/check-if-all-values-in-data-frame-columns-are-integers-to-subset-dummy-variables)

Comment: `mpg %>% mutate(across(where(is.integer), factor))`.  There could be dupes for this

Comment: That could be it, however some of the columns that do contain integers are encoded as "numeric".

Comment: Yes, in the `mpg`, there is only one column that is `dbl` (numeric) - displ.  So, if you do `is.integer`, it should correctly select only integer columns i.e. `mpg %>% select(where(is.integer))`  If you want both numeric as well, use `is.numeric` which select both integer and double `mpg %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), factor))`

Comment: I am sorry, I had to mention mtcars, instead of mpg. I found the solution in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60549597/check-if-all-values-in-data-frame-columns-are-integers-to-subset-dummy-variables

Comment: Can i tag this as duplicate

Comment: Sure. Do you want me to delete it, or should I let it be, in case anyone else has a similar question?

Comment: Not really.  dupe tagging helps in finding the post more easily for others

Comment: Does this answer your question? [check if all values in data.frame columns are integers to subset dummy variables aka are all values in a column TRUE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60549597/check-if-all-values-in-data-frame-columns-are-integers-to-subset-dummy-variables)