# While loop misses the first try in R

Tags: r, while-loop

I want to print reversed binary number of `x`, but its first digit wouldn't come out.
For example, If I put

```
dbf(35)
```

results should be

```
110001
```

but it comes out as

```
10001
```

I think something must be wrong with the `while` loop, but cannot figure  out exactly what.

```
dbf<-function(x){
  vec<-1:5
  while(x%/%2!=0){
    if(is.integer(x)==F){
      x<-x%/%2
    } else {
      x<-x/2
    }
    vec<-append(vec, x%%2)
  }
  
  vec<-vec[-(1:5)]
  
  cat(vec)
}
```

Comment: [`is.integer` does not test whether a number does not have a decimal part.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476782/check-if-the-number-is-integer)

Comment: @RuiBarradas Yup I know but I used `is.integer` to make `x` always be integer, since if it's not integer, outcome would have decimal points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function in the question is complicating too much.

```r
dbf <- function(x){
  vec <- x %% 2
  while(x %/% 2 != 0){
    x <- x %/% 2
    vec <- append(vec, x %% 2)
  }
  vec
}

dbf(35)
#> [1] 1 1 0 0 0 1

sapply(2:6, dbf)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 0 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1 1
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 0 0 1
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 1 0 1
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 0 1 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>