# R rounding explanation

Tags: r

can any one please explain why this gives different outputs?

```
round(1.49999999999999)
1


round(1.4999999999999999)
2
```

I have read the round documentation but it does not mention anything about it there.
I know that R represents numbers in binary form, but why does adding two extra 9's changes the result?

Thanks.

Comment: See [this answer][1] about problems in R.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535021/whats-the-biggest-r-gotcha-youve-run-across/3398868#3398868

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`1.4999999999999999` can't be represented internally, so it gets rounded to `1.5`.

Now, when you apply `round()`, the result is `2`.

Comment: Thanks, R can give some strange results with decimals sometimes.

Comment: @user557240 There's nothing peculiar about R in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

Put those two numbers into  variable and then print it - you'll see they are different.

Computers doesn't store this kind of numbers with this exact value, (They don't use decadic numbers internaly)

Comment: You'd better set `options(digits=20)` before you print them, or they will **look** identical

Comment: As noted in other responses - the 1.4999999999999999  is stored as 1.5 so you wont get the same result!

Answer (score 2):

I have never used R, so I don't know is this is the issue, but in other languages such as C/C++ a number like 1.4999999999999999 is represented by a float or a double.

Since these have finite precision, you cannot represent something like 1.4999999999999999 exactly. It might be the case that 1.4999999999999999 actually gets stored as 1.50000000000000 instead due to limitations on floating point precision.

Comment: R does use IEEE floating point arithmetic, so it has the same issues.