# R (and python) rounding up starting at 5 or 6

Tags: r, python-3.x, math

I saw already a question with very large number of decimal digits [R rounding explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931668/r-rounding-explanation).

```
round(62.495, digits=2)
```

gives me 62.49. I would expect already 62.5, but it seems, R (3.4.3, 3.5.0) rounds up only starting at 6, e.g.,

```
round(62.485, 2) == 62.48
round(62.486, 2) == 62.49.
```

For other reasons, I am using the option

```
options(digits.secs=6)
```

From what I have learnt, one rounds up starting at **5**. I tested also with Python and Matlab. Matlab rounds up, Python 3.5.4 down.

How can I change the behaviour or is this definition different, e.g. between Europe and US?

Comment: In `R3.5.0` it works for me: `round(62.495, 1)`

Comment: note that `round(5.5)` returns `6` but `round(5.55,1)` returns `5.5`

Comment: `sprintf("%.16f", 62.495)`

Comment: PS I think you meant to write `round(62.485,2) == 62.48`

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood how computer systems perform rounding.  Computers systems, such as R, use the IEEE standard for rounding (IEEE 60559, I believe), which states that when a value ends in a _precise_ 5, it is rounded to the nearest _even_ digit in the next place.  That _precise_ term is important, however, for reasons illustrated in James's answer.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/39913257/1017276

Comment: I edited the question. Indeed, I meant round(62.485,2)

Comment: I understood now the "round to even". Out of curiosity, why is it defined that way and not always round up or round down?

Comment: In short, it produces less bias in estimation due to rounding error.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even

Answer (score 4):

This is a floating point representation issue, 62.495 is actually represented by a slightly smaller number which then gets rounded downwards.

```
print(62.495,digits=22)
[1] 62.49499999999999744205
```

R's rounding is statistical rounding, or round half to even. It should round halves up or down to an even number, eg

```
round(0.5) # rounds the half down to 0
[1] 0
round(1.5) # rounds the half up to 2
[1] 2
```