# Error in if/while (condition) { : argument is of length zero

Tags: r, r-faq

I received the error

```
Error in if (condition) { : argument is of length zero
```

or

```
Error in while (condition) { : argument is of length zero
```

**What causes this error message, and what does it mean?**

On further inspection it seems that the value is `NULL`.

```
condition
## NULL
```

**In order to deal with this error, how do I test for NULL values?**

I expected that this would return `TRUE`, but I got an empty logical value:

```
condition == NULL
## logical(0)
```

Comment: use `is.null` instead of `==`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

See `?NULL`

You have to use `is.null`

> ‘is.null’ returns ‘TRUE’ if its argument is ‘NULL’ and ‘FALSE’
>        otherwise.

Try this:

```
if ( is.null(hic.data[[z]]) ) { print("is null")}
```

---

From section 2.1.6 of the [R Language Definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.pdf)

> There is a special object called NULL. It is used whenever there is a need to indicate or
>   specify that an object is absent. It should not be confused with a vector or list of zero
>   length.
>   The NULL object has no type and no modifiable properties. There is only one NULL object
>   in R, to which all instances refer. To test for NULL use is.null. You cannot set attributes
>   on NULL.

Answer (score 16):

**What causes this error message, and what does it mean?**

`if` statements take a single logical value (technically a logical vector of length one) as an input for the condition.

The error is thrown when the input condition is of length zero.  You can reproduce it with, for example:

```
if (logical()) {}
## Error: argument is of length zero

if (NULL) {}
## Error: argument is of length zero
```

---

**Common mistakes that lead to this error**

It is easy to accidentally cause this error when using `$` indexing.  For example:

```
l <- list(a = TRUE, b = FALSE, c = NA)
if(l$d) {}   
## Error in if (l$d) { : argument is of length zero
```

Also [using `if`-`else` when you meant `ifelse`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17252905/134830), or [overriding `T` and `F`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6150337/134830).

---

Note these related errors and warnings for other bad conditions:

[Error in if/while (condition) {: missing Value where TRUE/FALSE needed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7355187/134830)

[Error in if/while (condition) : argument is not interpretable as logical](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27659841/134830)

```
if (NA) {}
## Error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

if ("not logical") {}
## Error: argument is not interpretable as logical

if (c(TRUE, FALSE)) {}
## Warning message:
## the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

---

**How do I test for such values?**

[`NULL`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/NULL) values can be tested for using `is.null`.  See [GSee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12307158/134830) for more detail.

To make your calls to `if` safe, a good code pattern is:

```
if(!is.null(condition) && 
   length(condition) == 1 && 
   !is.na(condition) && 
   condition) {
  # do something
}
```

You may also want to look at [`assert_is_if_condition`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/assertive.code/topics/assert_is_if_condition) from `assertive.code`.

Comment: The fact that this is a "good pattern" is fairly embarrassing for R.

Answer (score 6):

When testing for NULL values, you want to use `is.null(hic.data[[z]])`.