# else if(){} VS ifelse()

Tags: r, vector, if-statement

Why can we use `ifelse()` but not `else if(){}` in `with()` or `within()` statement ?

I heard the first is vectorizable and not the latter. What does it mean ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `if` construct only considers the first component when a vector is passed to it, (and gives a warning)

```
if(sample(100,10)>50) 
    print("first component greater 50") 
else 
    print("first component less/equal 50")
```

The `ifelse` function performs the check on each component and returns a vector

```
ifelse(sample(100,10)>50, "greater 50", "less/equal 50")
```

The `ifelse` function is useful for `transform`, for instance. It is often useful to
use `&` or `|` in `ifelse` conditions and `&&` or `||` in `if`.

Answer (score 10):

Answer for your second part:

****Using `if` when x has length of 1 but that of y is greater than 1 ****

```
 x <- 4
 y <- c(8, 10, 12, 3, 17)
if (x < y) x else y

[1]  8 10 12  3 17
Warning message:
In if (x < y) x else y :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

***Using`ifelse` when x has length of 1 but that of y is greater than 1***

```
ifelse (x < y,x,y)
[1] 4 4 4 3 4
```

Comment: this is super interesting. i might actually consider it a disadvantage, preferring to get a warning if I try to compare an int and list