# Warning message using if function in data.table

Tags: r, function, data.table, sapply

I have a custom function that includes the function IF. When I use that function in a data.table, I get a warning that  says
"the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used".

I think the function may be applied to all rows in the column rather than one row at a time as needed, but I am not certain.

Is anyone aware of why this warning appears?

My function is:

```
HeatIndex<-function(TempC,RH)
{
TFarheit= TempC * 1.8 + 32
if( TFarheit <80  ) {
   Te=TempC /15
   HI = Te/15
} else {
   TA=TempC /11
   HI = TA/125
}
HI= (HI - 32) / 1.8
return(HI )
}
```

A sample of the data:

```
HeatINDEX=data.table(Ave_MeanRH=c(0,100), Ave_MeanT=c(10,20))   #create data.table
```

And applying the function to the data

```
HeatINDEX[,HI:=HeatIndex(HeatINDEX$Ave_MeanT, HeatINDEX$Ave_MeanRH)]
```

Comment: the 'quick' solution is to specify you want it to apply to each row in `by` : `HeatINDEX[,HI:=HeatIndex(Ave_MeanT, Ave_MeanRH), by = 1:nrow(HeatINDEX)]  `

Comment: Usually best to use `ifelse` for these kinds of comparisons, rather than `if`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252905/else-if-vs-ifelse

Comment: using the "by" parameter still keeps the warning. and in a larger database it takes a lot of time to run the function to all rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can vectorize your heat index function by using `ifelse()`. This will certainly be faster than computing row-by-row, another solution suggested in the comments.

```
# Vectorized version of function:
computeHI = function(T_cel, RH) {
    T_far = T_cel * 1.8 + 32
    HI = ifelse(test=T_far < 80, 
                 yes=(T_cel / 15) / 15, 
                  no=(T_cel / 11) / 125)
    HI = (HI - 32) / 1.8
    return(HI)
}

HeatINDEX[,HI:=HeatIndex(Ave_MeanT, Ave_MeanRH), by=seq(2)]
HeatINDEX[,vectorized_HI:=computeHI(Ave_MeanT, Ave_MeanRH)]

HeatINDEX
#    Ave_MeanRH Ave_MeanT        HI vectorized_HI
# 1:          0        10 -17.75309     -17.75309
# 2:        100        20 -17.72840     -17.72840
```

Comment: I wonder if you can speed this up further by avoiding the C -> F and F -> C conversions?

Comment: Just a heads up, these calculated heat index numbers don't seem to make any sense. You may want to double check the math! But at least you know how to vectorize now.

Comment: The function is just a demo to demonstrate the error. For some reason, the calculation is applied to only the first row, when using ifelse

Comment: Hard to say what the issue is without examining the input data.table and columns. It's working as expected with the tiny example in my posted answer.

Comment: yes, it is working well. I was using another conditional with &&, and forgot that ifelse likes just one &, thanks