# Returning error in elsif statment R Studio

Tags: r

This statement should change the value of `allmonths$DIVauth` to either `1` or `o` based on a comparison of the values of `$cfs` and `$Tess`. Instead, it returns the following error and puts the value `1` in every row:

```
The condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used.
```

My statement:

```
if (allmonths$cfs >= allmonths$Tess) {
    allmonths$DIVauth <- 1
} else {
    allmonths$DIVauth <- 0
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: also, look at the error message and work out what is wrong with your code. Debug 101 - break it down to small pieces and work out what is happening.type  `allmonths$cfs >= allmonths$Tess` into your console. And so on

Comment: You should post sample data. Possibly you should be using `ifelse` instead of `if`. More: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252905/else-if-vs-ifelse Something like `allmonths$DIVauth <- ifelse(allmonths$cfs >= allmonths$Tess, 1, 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work as intended?

```
allmonths$DIVauth <- ifelse(allmonths$cfs >= allmonths$Tess, 1, 0)
```

Why does `ifelse` work when `if` fails? Quoting @karsten-w and adapting the provided sample:
"The `if` construct only considers the first component when a vector is passed to it (and gives a warning)... The `ifelse` function performs the check on each component and returns a vector."
[else if(){} VS ifelse()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252905/else-if-vs-ifelse)

Example:

```
set.seed(1) # make following random data same for everyone
data <- sample(100, 5)
data
```

> [1] 27 37 57 89 20

```
if(data > 50) {
    print("1st item > 50") 
} else {
    print("1st item <= 50")
}
```

> [1] "1st item <= 50"
>      Warning message:
>      In if (data > 50) { :
>          the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be use

```
ifelse(data > 50, "> 50", "<= 50")
```

> [1] "<= 50" "<= 50" "> 50"  "> 50"  "<= 50"

Comment: Yes it did Thank you!!!! it worked perfectly.

Comment: @ISJohnny Great. Remember to mark the checkbox to indicate this answer works.