# How to reference a variable which is not in data.table header?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table DT, which contains 2 columns.

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(a = c(1, 2), b = c(2, 3))
```

I have a variable, named i

```
i <- "A"
```

Now I want to use `i` to determine how to create a new column in data.table. If `i == "A"`, I want to create a new column, which is `a*b`.

However, if I use `DT[ , NEW := ifelse(i == "A", a*b, a)]`

The result is in below, which is not what I want.

```
   a b NEW
1: 1 2   2
2: 2 3   2
```

The result that I am looking for is

```
   a b NEW
1: 1 2   2
2: 2 3   6
```

I know if I generate a new column named i, I can get what I want.

```
DT[ , i := i]
DT[ , NEW := ifelse(i == "A", a*b, a)]
   a b i NEW
1: 1 2 A   2
2: 2 3 A   6
```

Is there a simple way to reference variable `i`, without generating a new column named `i`?

Thanks

Comment: use `if`/`else` not `ifelse`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252905/else-if-vs-ifelse

Comment: also may be a situation where you consider using `switch`; see `?switch`

Comment: Or raise 'b' to the power of your logical test, `DT[ , NEW := a * b^(i == "A")]`

Comment: @MichaelChirico Thank you! Simple if/else works.

Comment: @Henrik Thank you. Your solution also works.