# Dependant variable column in R

Tags: r, assign, datasheet

I'm trying to add a newcolumn of information to a data table in R,
I have a column

```
dataSheet$day
```

with numerical values 1 to 3 with 1 being Thursday, 2 being Friday and 3 being Saturday
I want to assign the value "week" or "weekend" to a new variable

```
dataSheet$t_week
```

With dataSheet$t_week being "week" when dataSheet$day is 1, and dataSheet$t_week being "weekend" when dataSheet$day is 2 or 3.
This is the code I tried:

```
if(dataSheet$day == 2) {dataSheet$t_week = "Week"} else {dataSheet$t_week = "Weekend"}
```

when I try this I get a column with every element in it being Weekend, regardless of the value in dataSheet$day. ( I think this might be the case because the first element in dataSheet$day is 2 and it iterates over it?)

Comment: just `dataSheet$t_week <- ifelse(dataSheet$day == 1, "Week", "Weekend")` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [else if(){} VS ifelse()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252905/else-if-vs-ifelse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without having data to work with, a good place to start is `ifelse()`:

```
dataSheet$t_week<- ifelse(dataSheet$day == 1, "Week", "Weekend")
```

Is this working for you? check it out.