# Multiple conditions while grouping data with NAs and empty cells

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, group-by

I have a data frame as follows:

```
ID=c(1,1,2,3,3,1,2,4,2,1,2,1,4,3,1,2,3)
text=c("a","","R","NA","","iy","","NA","ot","ir","","NA","","","","","NA")

df <- data.frame(ID,text)
```

```
df %>% arrange(ID)

   ID text
1   1    a
2   1     
3   1   iy
4   1   ir
5   1   NA
6   1     
7   2    R
8   2     
9   2   ot
10  2     
11  2     
12  3   NA
13  3     
14  3     
15  3   NA
16  4   NA
17  4
```

For each `ID` I have a `character/ text` collected. I can have `NA` values and/or `empty` values corresponding to `IDs`.
I would like to create a binary column to present if there is `text available` to any of the text rows collected for an `ID`. I am running this code:

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise(text_availabe=if(any(!is.na(text))) 1 else 0)
```

which populates the following where for `ID 3` and `ID 4`, it treats empty cells as they have text.

```
     ID text_availabe
  <dbl>         <dbl>
1     1             1
2     2             1
3     3             1
4     4             1
```

My idea output in this case should be like:

```
     ID text_availabe
  <dbl>         <dbl>
1     1             1
2     2             1
3     3             0
4     4             0
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: @Ronak Shah, wondering if you can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you are having is that `"NA"` is not the same as `NA`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarize(text_available = any(!text %in% c("", "NA")), .groups = "drop")
```

```
!is.na("NA")
[1] TRUE
```

This is a character string with the letters "N" and "A", so it returns `TRUE`.

**Output**

Logical columns are representations of `1` and `0`:

```
TRUE == 1
[1] TRUE
```

But if you need it to be in 1/0 form, then just wrap it with `as.integer`: `as.integer(any(...))`.

```
     ID text_available
  <dbl> <lgl>         
1     1 TRUE          
2     2 TRUE          
3     3 FALSE         
4     4 FALSE
```

Comment: would it be OK if I use `if` instead of `as.integer`  like `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise(text_availabe=if(any(!text %in% c("", "NA"))) 1 else 0)`

Comment: Use the vectorized form of `if`, which is `ifelse`. You can do: `ifelse(any(!text %in% c("", "NA")), 1, 0)`. `If` and `else` is reserved for conditions of length 1.

Comment: Thanks! well, can you elaborate on vectorized form of `if`. The above code gives me the same output as using `if` and `else` that you are proposing.

Comment: Actually, in this context `if` and `else` works. Because you are creating one logical value using `any` they will return the same thing. Generally, in pipe chains and in `mutate` you are evaluating a condition across many rows resulting in a logical *vector* rather than a single logical value, which is when you would use `if` and `else`.

Comment: Consider reading this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252905/else-if-vs-ifelse) for a more in-depth answer.

Comment: thanks! I read through it and I think I noticed what you meant. Would you mind rating the question if you think it has value. Appreciated!

Comment: thanks! the piece of code worked well on the real data which had ~ 780 rows

Comment: my apologies, I thought in my mind that I did so yesterday.