# Using IF/AND/ELSE Logic in R

Tags: r

Edited to make reproducible, I think.

I have a similar table to this:

```
UnitID <- c(177834,180203,222178,138558)
Year <- c(2019,2019,2019,2019)
EndowmentF <- c(108431567,NA,444076565,NA)
EndowmentG_ID<-c(177834,180203,222178,138558)
EndowmentG_YR <- c(2019,2019,2019,2019)
EndowmentG <- c(NA,1220803,NA,17251420)
Endow <- data.frame(UnitID,Year,EndowmentF,EndowmentG_ID,EndowmentG_YR,EndowmentG)
```

I attempt to create a new variable called `Endowment` because the original data was reported in two tables based on different reporting methods. When I use the following code I get an error and the variable isn't computed:

```
Endowments <- Endow %>% mutate(
  Endowment= if(UnitID=EndowmentG_ID && Year=EndowmentG_YR && is.na(EndowmentG))
  {EndowmentF} else {EndowmentG})
```

I get the following error in the console and am not sure what I have done wrong. Any help or advice would be great. I was able to get this to work in Excel using IF/AND Logic but not sure how to fix it in R.

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"Endowments <- Endow %>% mutate(
  Endowment= if(UnitID="
>   {EndowmentF} else {EndowmentG})
Error: unexpected 'else' in "  {EndowmentF} else"
```

Comment: I think I have made a reproducible example. Thanks for having patience with me on this since I am still fairly new to this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252905/else-if-vs-ifelse

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may use `ifelse` since it is vectorized.

```
library(dplyr)

Endow <- Endow %>%
  mutate(Endowment = ifelse(UnitID == EndowmentG_ID & Year == EndowmentG_YR & 
                            is.na(EndowmentG), EndowmentF, EndowmentG))
Endow

#  UnitID Year EndowmentF EndowmentG_ID EndowmentG_YR EndowmentG Endowment
#1 177834 2019  108431567        177834          2019         NA 108431567
#2 180203 2019         NA        180203          2019    1220803   1220803
#3 222178 2019  444076565        222178          2019         NA 444076565
#4 138558 2019         NA        138558          2019   17251420  17251420
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this chunk of code and I think the problem is you should use `==` instead of `=` for conditional phrases:

```
   Endowments <- Endow %>% mutate(
   if(UnitID == EndowmentG_ID && Year == EndowmentG_YR && is.na(EndowmentG)){
      Endowment = EndowmentF} else {
         Endowment = EndowmentG
         }
   )
```