# Error in if/while (condition) : argument is not interpretable as logical

Tags: r, r-faq

I received the error

```
Error in if (condition) { : argument is not interpretable as logical
```

or

```
Error in while (condition) { : argument is not interpretable as logical
```

What does it mean, and how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 14):

The evaluation of `condition` resulted in something that R could not interpret as logical.  You can reproduce this with, for example,

```
if("not logical") {}
Error in if ("not logical") { : argument is not interpretable as logical
```

---

In `if` and `while` conditions, R will interpret zero as `FALSE` and non-zero numbers as `TRUE`.

```
if(1) 
{
  "1 was interpreted as TRUE"
}
## [1] "1 was interpreted as TRUE"
```

This is dangerous however, since calculations that return `NaN` cause this error.

```
if(sqrt(-1)) {}
## Error in if (sqrt(-1)) { : argument is not interpretable as logical
## In addition: Warning message:
## In sqrt(-1) : NaNs produced
```

It is better to always pass a logical value as the `if` or `while` conditional.  This usually means an expression that includes a [comparison operator](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/Comparison) (`==`, etc.) or [logical operator](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/Logic) (`&&`, etc.).

Using `isTRUE` can sometimes be helpful to prevent this sort of error but note that, for example, `isTRUE(NaN)` is `FALSE`, which may or may not be what you want.

```
if(isTRUE(NaN)) 
{
  "isTRUE(NaN) was interpreted as TRUE"
} else
{
  "isTRUE(NaN) was interpreted as FALSE"
}
## [1] "isTRUE(NaN) was interpreted as FALSE"
```

---

Similarly, the strings `"TRUE"`/`"true"`/`"T"`, and `"FALSE"`/`"false"`/`"F"` can be used as logical conditions.

```
if("T") 
{
  "'T' was interpreted as TRUE"
}
## [1] "'T' was interpreted as TRUE"
```

Again, this is a little dangerous because other strings cause the error.

```
if("TRue") {}
Error in if ("TRue") { : argument is not interpretable as logical
```

---

See also the related errors:

[Error in if/while (condition) { : argument is of length zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12307139/134830)

[Error in if/while (condition) {: missing Value where TRUE/FALSE needed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7355187/134830)

```
if (NULL) {}
## Error in if (NULL) { : argument is of length zero

if (NA) {}
## Error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

if (c(TRUE, FALSE)) {}
## Warning message:
## the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: The most defensive thing you can do to prevent an execution error is to always use `if(isTRUE(cond))`.