# How do I overcome this error in execution of lmer function: Error in if (REML) p else 0L : argument is not interpretable as logical?

Tags: r, lme4

I have checked out the defensive methods as was discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659841/error-in-if-while-condition-argument-is-not-interpretable-as-logical) in order to prevent this error but it still doesn't go away.

```
model<-lmer(Proportion~Plot+Treatment+(1|Plot/Treatment),binomial,data=data)
```

> Error in if (REML) p else 0L : argument is not interpretable as logical

Comment: Ok thanks. So how do I explicitly state that the entire argument is binomial? In Crawley's R book, he simply uses this formula:
    model<-lmer(y~block+treatment+(1|block/treatment),binomial,data=data)
    summary(model)

Comment: Apparently this is a typo and you actually want to use the `glmer` function? When in doubt study the documentation, e.g., `help("lmer")` and `help("glmer")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** you should use `glmer` instead.  Because you haven't named your arguments, R is interpreting them by position (order). `lmer`'s third argument is `REML`, so R thinks you're specifying `REML=binomial`, which isn't a legitimate value. `family` *is* the third argument to `glmer`, so this would work (sort of: see below) if you used `glmer`, but it's usually safer to name the arguments explicitly if there's any possibility of getting confused.

A reproducible example would be nice, but:

```
model <- glmer(Proportion~Plot+Treatment+(1|Plot/Treatment),
    family=binomial,data=data)
```

is a starting point. I foresee a few more problems though:

- if your data are not Bernoulli (0/1) (which I'm guessing not since your response is called `Proportion`), then you need to include the total number sampled in each trial, e.g. by specifying a `weights` argument
- you have `Plot` and `Treatment` as both fixed and as random-effect grouping variables in your model; that won't work. I see that Crawley [really does suggest this in the R book](https://books.google.ca/books?id=8D4HVx0apZQC&lpg=PA590&dq=crawley%20block%20treatment%20binomial&pg=PA590#v=onepage&q=crawley%20block%20treatment%20binomial&f=false) (google books link).

**Do not do it the way he suggests, it doesn't make any sense**. Replicating:

```
library(RCurl)
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jejoenje/Crawley/master/Data/insects.txt"
dd <- read.delim(text=getURL(url),header=TRUE)
## fix typo because I'm obsessive:
levels(dd$treatment) <- c("control","sprayed") 
library(lme4)
model <- glmer(cbind(dead,alive)~block+treatment+(1|block/treatment),
               data=dd,family=binomial)
```

If we look at the among-group standard deviation, we see that it's zero for both groups; it's *exactly* zero for `block` because `block` is already included in the fixed effects. It need not be for the `treatment:block` interaction (we have `treatment`, but not the interaction between `block` and `treatment`, in the fixed effects), but is because there's little among-treatment-within-block variation:

```
VarCorr(model)
##  Groups          Name        Std.Dev.  
##  treatment:block (Intercept) 2.8736e-09
##  block           (Intercept) 0.0000e+00
```

Conceptually, it makes more sense to treat block as a random effect:

```
dd <- transform(dd,prop=dead/(alive+dead),ntot=alive+dead)
model1 <- glmer(prop~treatment+(1|block/treatment),
               weights=ntot,
               data=dd,family=binomial)
summary(model)
## ...
## Formula: prop ~ treatment + (1 | block/treatment)
## Random effects:
##  Groups          Name        Variance Std.Dev.
##  treatment:block (Intercept) 0.02421  0.1556  
##  block           (Intercept) 0.18769  0.4332  
## Number of obs: 48, groups:  treatment:block, 12; block, 6
## 
## Fixed effects:
##                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
## (Intercept)       -1.1640     0.2042  -5.701 1.19e-08 ***
## treatmentsprayed   3.2434     0.1528  21.230  < 2e-16 ***
```

Sometimes you *might* want to treat it as a fixed effect:

```
model2 <- update(model1,.~treatment+block+(1|block:treatment))
summary(model2)
## Random effects:
##  Groups          Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
##  block:treatment (Intercept) 5.216e-18 2.284e-09
## Number of obs: 48, groups:  block:treatment, 12
## 
## Fixed effects:
##                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
## (Intercept)       -0.5076     0.0739  -6.868 6.50e-12 ***
## treatmentsprayed   3.2676     0.1182  27.642  < 2e-16 ***
```

Now the block-by-treatment interaction variance is effectively zero (because block soaks up more variability if treated as a fixed effect). However, the estimated effect of spraying is very nearly identical.

If you're worried about overdispersion you can add an individual-level random effect (or use `MASS::glmmPQL`; `lme4` no longer fits quasi-likelihood models)

```
dd <- transform(dd,obs=factor(seq(1:nrow(dd))))
model3 <- update(model1,.~.+(1|obs))

## Random effects:
##  Groups          Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
##  obs             (Intercept) 4.647e-01 6.817e-01
##  treatment:block (Intercept) 1.138e-09 3.373e-05
##  block           (Intercept) 1.813e-01 4.258e-01
## Number of obs: 48, groups:  obs, 48; treatment:block, 12; block, 6
## 
## Fixed effects:
##                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
## (Intercept)       -1.1807     0.2411  -4.897 9.74e-07 ***
## treatmentsprayed   3.3481     0.2457  13.626  < 2e-16 ***
```

The observation-level effect has effectively replaced the treatment-by-block interaction (which is now close to zero). Again, the estimated spraying effect has hardly changed (but its standard error *is* twice as large ...)