# Error in if (plot) plot.roc(roc, ...) : argument is not interpretable as logical when trying to plot AUC graph

Tags: r, roc

I am trying to get an AUC plot for a regression model I created in R and for 
some reason I get the following error
"Error in if (plot) plot.roc(roc, ...) : argument is not interpretable as logical"

This is my code:

```
glm.fit <- glm(TARGET ~ NAME_CONTRACT_TYPE, data = application_train, family = binomial)
model_predtraining<-predict(glm.fit,application_train,type = 'response')
roc(model_predtraining,application_train$TARGET,main='ROC Training',plot = 'ROC',PV = FALSE,MI = FALSE)
```

it seems the model is created and predictions are calculated fine,its probably a mistake I made in the last line of code.
I saw a few posts related to this error
but they are not in the context of the roc function and I don't really understand the explanation.
[Error in if/while (condition) : argument is not interpretable as logical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659841/error-in-if-while-condition-argument-is-not-interpretable-as-logical)

Any help will be highly appriciated

Comment: If you are using `roc()` from the `pROC` package then the argument should be a logical ie `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Refer to the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pROC/pROC.pdf) for more details

Comment: What are `PV` and `MI` even supposed to do? Have you had a look at [`?roc`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pROC/topics/roc)?