# Why is my 'if' argument not interpretable as logical

Tags: r, dplyr, data-munging

I am working through some data and trying to do some conditional filtering. I want to write a statement that assesses if one variable is equal to a number (in this case, 1) and, if so, filters based on the value of another column. The result should be that all AtBatPitchSequences == 1 also have PitchType == "FA".

- Please note that if AtBatPitchSequence > 1 it should not be filtered, so row 4 should be kept after the filter

My data (firsttwopitches) looks like this:

```
  YearID GameID GamePitchSequen~ PAofInning AtBatPitchSeque~ Inning Balls Strikes PitchType
   <dbl> <chr>             <dbl>      <dbl>            <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>     <chr>
1   2018 DFCBC~                1          1                1      1     0       0        FA
2   2018 DFCBC~                2          1                2      1     1       0        FA
3   2018 DFCBC~                4          2                1      1     0       0        FA
4   2018 DFCBC~                5          2                2      1     0       1        SI
5   2018 DFCBC~                8          3                1      1     0       0        FA
6   2018 DFCBC~                9          3                2      1     0       1        FA
```

To address this problem, I am trying to use an if statement:

```
library(tidyverse)

firsttwopitches %>%
  if (AtBatPitchSequence == 1) {
    filter(PitchType == "FA")
  }
```

However, this raises an error and a warning:

```
Error in if (.) AtBatPitchSequence == 1 else { : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (.) AtBatPitchSequence == 1 else { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I do not understand why my argument is not interpretable as logical. In my head, it should assess whether AtBatPitchSequence equals 1 or not, then move on to the next row. Also, what does the warning message mean? If this warning is dealt with by correcting my if statement, don't worry about it, but I am still new and am trying to debug my own work better. I read through this [Error in if/while (condition) : argument is not interpretable as logical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659841/error-in-if-while-condition-argument-is-not-interpretable-as-logical) question and others to try and find my error but was unsuccessful.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a `&` condition in `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
firsttwopitches %>%   
   filter(AtBatPitchSequence == 1, PitchType == "FA")
```

If we want to keep rows where 'AtBatPitchSequence' is not equal to 1, then add another expression with `|`

```
firsttwopitches %>% 
    filter((AtBatPitchSequence == 1 & PitchType == "FA")|AtBatPitchSequence != 1)
```

---

There are two issues - 1) `if/else` are not vectorized, 2) related to the blocking of the code with `{}` especially when it is used in a pipe (`%>%`).  A related issue is also in finding the column name `AtBatPitchSequence` outside the tidyverse functions i.e `mutate`, `summarise` etc.  In that case we need to specify the data as well `.$AtBatPitchSequence`

---

The error/warning can be reproduced with the inbuilt dataset

```
data(iris)
head(iris) %>% 
   if(Species == 'setosa') {
       filter(Petal.Length > 1.5)
    }
```

> Error in if (.) Species == "setosa" else { :
> argument is not interpretable as logical
> In addition: Warning message:
> In if (.) Species == "setosa" else { :
> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Now, we can remove the error by blocking within `{}`, but note that the warning remains as `if/else` is not vectorized and this could give an incorrect output as well (Below output is correct, but it is only because there was only one row with the TRUE condition met)

```
head(iris) %>% 
    {if(.$Species == 'setosa') {
        filter(., Petal.Length > 1.5)
     }}
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

> Warning message:
> In if (.$Species == "setosa") { :
> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

If we use multiple expressions in `filter` (`,` will generate the `&`)

```
head(iris) %>% 
    filter(Species == 'setosa', Petal.Length > 1.5)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer that makes more sense. However, I believe I misled you in the question. I want to keep rows that have AtBatPitchSequence = 2 and PitchType != FA. For example, I want to keep row 4 in my example data set. However if AtBatPitchSequence = 1 and PitchType = SI I want it removed

Comment: @ChrisEwanik So, if it is only meant for 1, then `firsttwopitches %>%   
   filter(AtBatPitchSequence == 1 & PitchType == "FA", AtBatPitchSequence != 1)`

Comment: @ChrisEwanik I updated the post.  It should be an `|` condition

Comment: There is no typo that I can see. It all works as I had hoped, thank you again!