# Calculator in R error in user inup and if statement

Tags: r, calculator

Basically, I want to make a calculator that gets the input from the user from which operation he wants to use, but I was testing what happens if after the user chooses the input, my code has a condition that prints depending what was the user input.
Why am I getting this error? What is wrong with the if and else statement?

My code:

```
    Adicao = "Adição"
Subtracao = "Subtração"
Multiplicacao = "Multiplicação"
Divisao = "Divisão"

print("Choice of operations:")
cat("1.", Adicao)
cat("2.", Subtracao)
cat("3.", Multiplicacao)
cat("4.", Divisao)

escolha <- as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter your choice: "))

if(escolha = 1){
  print("Cool! You choose addition")
} else {
  print("You didnt choose addition ")
}
```

The error I get:

```
> escolha <- as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter your choice: "))
Enter your choice: 2
> if(escolha = 1){
Error: unexpected '=' in "if(escolha ="
>   print("Cool! You choose addition")
[1] "Cool! You choose addition"
> } else {
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
>   print("You didnt choose addition ")
[1] "You didnt choose addition "
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `==` equality operator for comparison in `if` statement which return logical (TRUE or FALSE) , `=` used to assign value to object

```
if(escolha == 1){
    print("Cool! You choose addition")
} else {
    print("You didnt choose addition ")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
print("Choice of operations:")
cat("1.", "Add\t")
cat("2.", "Subtract\t")
cat("3.", "Multiply\t")
cat("4.", "Divide\n")

userSelected <- as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter your choice: "))

if(all.equal(1, as.integer(userSelected)) == TRUE) {
  print("Add")
} else {
  print("You didnt choose addition")
}
```

#### Related Links

- [Unexpected 'else' in "else" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865435/unexpected-else-in-else-error)
- [Error in if/while (condition) : argument is not interpretable as logical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659841/error-in-if-while-condition-argument-is-not-interpretable-as-logical)
- [Check if the number is integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476782/check-if-the-number-is-integer)