# R view() function yields error when including rows with NA

Tags: r

This is the sample data frame

```
> training

         x1          x2      x3         x4        x5                    x6             x7
1:       26           8  Friday       <NA>         1                    NA           <NA>
2:        8           9  Friday 1070080727         1   IMPULSE MERCHANDISE            115
```

When using `View(training)` it yields error

```
Error in if (col_min < col_max) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

When only `View(training[1,])` , it is OK.

Saw similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355187/error-in-if-while-condition-missing-value-where-true-false-needed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307139/error-in-if-while-condition-argument-is-of-length-zero), but how can I fix the View()?

Comment: I guess because of NA in columns x4 and x6 ,col_min and col_max are NA for those columns . Remove  NA from those  columns.It'll definitely work

Comment: I can not replicate the error. Can you please provide a subset of your data with dput(head(training))

Comment: It works if you dont have "<NA>" in your data frame, instead you should have "NA".

Comment: Thank you guys for your time, `fread()` the x4 col as factor/char solved the problem.