# Receiving error while trying to loop an if condition: "argument is of length zero"

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to check if all cells of a column of a dataframe contain a word of all cells of another dataframe.

I successfully checked if a certain cell of a dataframe contains a certain cell of another dataframe with the following code:

```
if(grep(geoplaces$name[1], adresses$Comments[1])){
  print("hello")
} else {
  print("error")
}
```

So now I want to loop that function for all rows of geoplaces$name and all rows of adresses$Comments:

So I added the following code:

```
 ig <- 1
 ia <- 1

 for(ia in 1:8){
     for(ig in 1:8){
         if(grep(geoplaces$name[ig], adresses$Comments[ia])){
             print("hello")
             ig <- ig + 1
         } else {
             print("error")
             ig <- ig + 1
         }
      }
      ia <- ia + 1
 }
```

However I'm receiving the following error:

> Error in if (grep(geoplaces$name[ig], adresses$Comments[ia])) { : 
>     argument is of length zero.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check out this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307139/error-in-if-while-condition-argument-is-of-length-zero. Add an is.null() check on the values used in your if statement before applying the logical test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `grep` returns an *index* rather than a logical value. You want to use `grepl` which will return a logical value.  See the [grep documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/grep).

edit:
A couple things can cause your followup error:

- `geoplaces` and/or `addresses` contain less than 8 rows of data
- `geoplaces` contains NA values that need to be handled before making the grepl comparison (R thinks the search pattern is undefined)

It's impossible to say without having the complete dataset. The base functions `is.na` and `nrow` can help deal with either possibility.

Comment: To add on to this: since `grep` returns the index of the match, when it cannot find a match, it returns a integer vector of length 0 (`integer(0)` in the console) which basically no functions (aside from `length`) know how to handle.

Comment: Well actually, after using grep1 the error now has been transformed to: 
 Error in if (grepl(geoplaces$name[ig], adresses$Comments[ia])) { : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical