# Why write.csv and read.csv are not consistent?

Tags: r, import, export, export-to-csv, read.table

The problem is simple, consider the following example:

```
m <- head(iris)
write.csv(m, file = 'm.csv')
m1 <- read.csv('m.csv')
```

The result of this is that `m1` is different from the original object `m` in that it has a new first column named "X". If I really wanted to make them equal, I have to use additional arguments, like in these two examples:

```
write.csv(m, file = 'm.csv', row.names = FALSE)
# and then
m1 <- read.csv('m.csv')
```

or

```
write.csv(m, file = 'm.csv')
m1 <- read.csv('m.csv', row.names = 1)
```

The question is, what is the reason of this difference? in particular, why if `write.csv` and `read.csv` are supposedly intended to stick to the Excel convention, the don't import the same object that was exported in the first place? To me this is a very counter intuitive behavior and highly undesirable.

(this results happens exactly the same if I use the csv2 variants of these functions)

Thanks in advance!

---

These are the data.frames `m` and `m1` if you prefer not to use R to see the example:

```
> m
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

> m1
  X Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Comment: Why is why they're inconsistent important? There's no way the defaults will be changed now. Out of curiosity, where does it say that `read.csv` and `write.csv` are supposed to use some Excel convention?

Comment: As I said before, I think that it is counter intuitive, but this is just my opinion. In particular, if `write.csv` and `read.csv` are a "fast" way to forget about the specifics and "just do what you need", this is very annoying. In my case I always forget about this detail. You can read about this Excel convention with `?write.table`.

Comment: @Juan so write yourself your own wrappers that set your preferred defaults.  This is after all a programming language.

Comment: I'm with @Juan on this one. *Totally undesirable*. Both functions should have the same concept of a *standard* file (`read.csv` uses the most common format) so we don't have to remember which function uses what, or have to go through the doc each time we use them. It was a bad design in the first place.

Comment: Serendipity? (Don't think I should offer that as an official answer tho...)

Comment: When `?write.table` provides an example of writing a CSV to input into Excel (I assume this is the "convention" you mention), it specifically says you need the equivalent of `read.csv('m.csv', row.names=1)` to read it back into R.  Even if lots of people find this counter-intuitive, it's not going to change now (these defaults are probably 10+ years old). Hence, why these defaults were chosen is a moot point, and your question doesn't really have an answer.

Comment: @flodel right, but you aren't going to get R changed now I would venture. Those functions have been like that for aeons.

Comment: As good as the Q may be, I'm voting to close because unless the usually silent R Core chime in with an official statement, any answers (if an answer can even be supplied) will be opinion & that is OT for SO.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I guess so. In the help file it uses the word "convention" explicitly, so there is no need for quotation marks I think, unless the help file itself it wrongly uses this term. My intention is not to ask for changing the functions of course, I just wanted to know so I can tell some students.

Comment: From `svn log src/library/utils/R/write.table.R` "r32344 | ripley | 2004-12-27 08:25:32 -0500 (Mon, 27 Dec 2004) | 4 lines; add write.csv[2]" (and in r34879, "allow write.csv(row.names=FALSE)")

Comment: @Juan: Sorry, I meant "convention" as an offense to Excel, not to you.

Comment: @flodel: it would be nice if there were a way to do this on-line, but I'm not aware of one. Juan, if you wanted you could post this issue as an answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535021/whats-the-biggest-r-gotcha-youve-run-across ...

Comment: @BenBolker. That's it! So the reason is that it was December 27th and Ripley was still under a big hungover. That, or he was not happy about the gifts he got for Christmas. Payback.

Comment: Because `read.csv` was written by the Lilliputians and `write.table` was written by the Blefuscudians. ;)

Comment: @BenBolker thanks for the cryptic information! I also posted the issue in he Q you suggested (great Q btw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my guess...

`write.table` writes a data.frame to a file and data.frames always have row names, so not writing row names by default would be throwing away information. (Yes, `write.table` will also write a matrix and matrices don't have to have row names, but data.frames are probably used much more often than matrices.)

`read.table` returns a data.frame but CSV files don't have any concept of row names, so someone may argue that it's counter-intuitive to assume, by default, that the first column of a CSV is a row name.

Now there may be a way to make these two functions consistent, but I would argue that writing to a text file isn't the best way to output/input data from one R session to another.  It's much safer/faster to use `save`, `load`, `saveRDS`, `readRDS`, etc.

Comment: This is probably the best answer we are going to get, unless Brian Ripley itself comes here and gives us some light! Thanks Joshua.

Comment: As the functions `save`, `load` and related are the best options to keep all the information, I think that in `write.csv` and `read.csv` priority should be given to ease of use (which would be achieved by not saving row names by default I think), but keeping the option of using `row.names = TRUE` while exporting.