# drop = TRUE doesn't drop factor levels in data.frame while in vector it does

Tags: r, dataframe, r-factor

There is an interesting option `drop = TRUE` in data.frame filtering, see excerpt from `help('[.data.frame')`:

> #### Usage
>
> S3 method for class 'data.frame'
>
> ```
> x[i, j, drop = ]
> ```

But when I try it on data.frame, it doesn't work!

```
> df = data.frame(a = c("europe", "asia", "oceania"), b = c(1, 2, 3))
>
> df[1:2,, drop = TRUE]$a
[1] europe asia  
Levels: asia europe oceania     <--- oceania shouldn't be here!!
>
```

I know there are other ways like

```
df2 <- droplevels(df[1:2,])
```

**but the documentation promised much more elegant way to do this, so why it doesn't work?** Is it a bug? Because I don't understand how this could be a feature...

**EDIT**: I was confused by `drop = TRUE` dropping factor levels for vectors, as [you can see here](http://quantitative-ecology.blogspot.cz/2008/02/drop-unused-factor-levels.html). It is not very intuitive that `[i, drop = TRUE]` drops factor levels and `[i, j, drop = TRUE]` does not!!

Comment: I think you need to go back and actually read the documentation you link to. Also, it is sufficient to do `droplevels(df[1:2,])` in one line.

Comment: Thanks to @joran and you all for explanations. But, **is it a reason for downvote if someone doesn't understand the documentation?** (I was confused by drop = TRUE working for vectors, see my EDIT). Now I might be tempted to delete quite interesting question with answers..

Comment: Who says I downvoted? In any case, if the documentation were in any way confusing or ambiguous, I think you might have a point. Otherwise, I think "lack of research" would apply in this case.

Comment: @Tomas: I agree with you (I didn't downvote), anyway SO community tend to not appreciate very much when people seem to not have read the documentation carefully... (it's a fierce world here ;) )

Comment: @joran, I didn't meant you particularly. I was confused by drop = TRUE dropping factor levels for vectors, see my EDIT!

Comment: you could add an answer with your final observation (which I agree is weird) to the list at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535021/whats-the-biggest-r-gotcha-youve-run-across

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The documentation clearly states:

> drop :   logical. If TRUE the result is coerced to the lowest possible
>   dimension. The default is to drop if only one column is left, but not
>   to drop if only one row is left.

This means that if `drop = TRUE` and the filtered `data.frame` results in a single column or row, the result is coerced to a vector/list instead of returning a single-column/single-row `data.frame`.

Therefore, this argument has no relation with levels dropping, and so the right way to eliminate exceeding levels is the one you mentioned (i.e. using `droplevels` function).

Comment: Thanks! This is a big confusion here, that `[i, drop = TRUE]` [does drop factor levels](http://quantitative-ecology.blogspot.cz/2008/02/drop-unused-factor-levels.html) and `[i, j, drop = TRUE]` does not!

Comment: @Tomas: yes, the choice of the name "drop" is probably not a really good idea... They could have used "simplify" as in `lapply/tapply()` functions, that is way clearer IMO...

Comment: yeah, but then the `simplify` argument is `simplify` in some places and `SIMPLIFY` in others (`mapply`, I think?) and the default is `TRUE` in some places and `FALSE` elsewhere ... sigh.

Answer (score 6):

This is an stumbling block for many people, because "drop does something different", as Peter Dalgaard explains in http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@stat.math.ethz.ch/msg22459.html  and digEmAll below.

If you want what you want use:

```
d2[] <- lapply(d2, function(x) if (is.factor(x)) factor(x) else x)
```

Comment: +1 for the link to an answer from an R-core member ... why not just `d2 <- droplevels(d2)` ... ?  Does your solution do something different/better? (I see that solution was suggested by Peter Dalgaard, but that was before `droplevels` was added to base R (in 2.13, I think?)

Comment: Correct, that was before ´droplevels´. I still find it useful because I see what happens. I learned about the d[]<- syntax from it. And old habits die hard.

Answer (score 6):

What documentation says is

> If TRUE the result is coerced to the lowest possible **dimension**.

So it is related to dimension, not to factor levels:

```
df[, 1]
# [1] europe  asia    oceania
# Levels: asia europe oceania
df[, 1, drop = FALSE]
#         a
# 1  europe
# 2    asia
# 3 oceania
```

Dropping factor levels is a different problem. Here is a case (`?'[.factor'`) where argument `drop` appears for this purpose:

```
ff <- factor(c('AA', 'BA', 'CA'))
ff[1:2, drop = TRUE]
# [1] AA BA
# Levels: AA BA
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a big confusion here, that `[i, drop = TRUE]` [does drop factor levels](http://quantitative-ecology.blogspot.cz/2008/02/drop-unused-factor-levels.html) and `[i, j, drop = TRUE]` does not!

Comment: It drops it if class is `factor`, but not a `data.frame`. Seems very straightforward to me.

Answer (score 1):

> df[1:2,]$a[,drop=TRUE]

[1] europe asia
Levels: asia europe

Yo Man so what happens when u try by your method is that it applies the drop on the original data frame so the result u want does not come ok

So what u need to do is apply the drop on the subset returned ok .....

If any queries then feel free to ping me ....

Comment: @AfshinMoazami what example do you want ,i just answerd the question ?