# Difference between mean and manual calculation in R?

Tags: r, math

I am writing a simple function in R to calculate percentage differences between two input numbers.

```
pdiff <-function(a,b) 
    {
      if(length(a>=1)) a <- median(a)
      if(length(b>=1)) b <- median(b)
      (abs(a-b)/((a+b)/2))*100
    }

    pdiffa <-function(a,b)
    {
      if(length(a>=1)) a <- median(a)
      if(length(b>=1)) b <- median(b)
      (abs(a-b)/mean(a,b))*100
    }
```

When you run it with a random value of a and b, the functions give different results

```
x <- 5
y <- 10
pdiff(x,y) #gives 66%
pdiffa(x,y) #gives 100%
```

[image]

When I go into the code, apparently the values of (x+y)/2 = 7.5 and mean(x,y) = 5 differ......Am I missing something really obvious and stupid here?

[image]

Comment: Try replacing `mean(a, b)` with `mean(c(a,b))`.

Comment: I think you don't really need the screenshots - the first is redundant with the information you have in your code chunk, and the second could easily (and preferably) be stated in text ...

Comment: @BenBolker, true. the reason its there is because i was thinking this was one of those non-reproducible errors, and not something so simple

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is due to a nasty "gotcha" in the `mean()` function (*not* listed in the [list of R traps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535021/whats-the-biggest-r-gotcha-youve-run-across), but probably should be): you want `mean(c(a,b))`, not `mean(a,b)`. From `?mean`:

> mean(x, ...) 
>   [*snip snip snip*] 
>   `...` further arguments passed to or from other methods.

So what happens if you call `mean(5,10)`? `mean` calls the `mean.default` method, which has `trim` as its second argument:

> `trim` the fraction (0 to 0.5) of observations to be trimmed from each end of x before the mean is computed. Values of trim outside that range are taken as the nearest endpoint.

The last phrase "values of trim outside that range are taken as the nearest endpoint" means that values of `trim` larger than 0.5 are set to 0.5, which means that we're asking `mean` to throw away 50% of the data **on either end of the data set**, which means that all that's left is the median. Debugging our way through `mean.default`, we see that we indeed end up at this code ...

```
if (trim >= 0.5) 
      return(stats::median(x, na.rm = FALSE))
```

So `mean(c(x,<value_greater_than_0.5>))` returns the median of `c(5)`, which is just 5 ...

Answer (score 5):

Try `mean(5, 10)` by itself.

```
mean(5, 10)
[1] 5
```

Now try `mean(c(5, 10))`.

```
mean(c(5, 10))
[1] 7.5
```

`mean` takes a vector as its first argument.