# R plot from Wikipedia: Numbers are falsely interpreted as factors

Tags: r, charts, statistics, wikimedia-commons

I have been trying to run the script of [this Wikipedia chart](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:US_Unemployment_measures.svg) showing US unemployment.

The data is from http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/ln/ln.data.1.AllData & http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/ln/ln.series

```
    cat("Loading table -- might take some time\n");
    u <- read.table("ln.data.1.AllData", header=T, fill=T)
    u$time <- u$year + (as.numeric(u$period) - 1) / 12

    cat("Processing -- might take some time\n");
    u1 = subset(u, series_id == "LNS13025670")
    u2 = subset(u, series_id == "LNS14023621")
    u3 = subset(u, series_id == "LNS14000000")
    u4 = subset(u, series_id == "LNS13327707")
    u5 = subset(u, series_id == "LNS13327708")
    u6 = subset(u, series_id == "LNS13327709")

par(family="Times")
par(bty = "n")
plot(
    0,
    main = "Measurement of unemployment",
    ylim = c(0,18),
    xlim = c(1950, 2010),
    xlab = "Year",
    ylab = "Percentage",
    las = 1
);

grid()

pal = rainbow(8)
lines(value ~ time, u6, col=pal[6])
lines(value ~ time, u5, col=pal[5])
lines(value ~ time, u4, col=pal[4])
lines(value ~ time, u3, col=pal[3])
lines(value ~ time, u2, col=pal[2])
lines(value ~ time, u1, col=pal[1])

legend(
    "topleft",
    rev(c(
        "U1: Percent Of Civilian Labor Force Unemployed 15 Weeks and over",
        "U2: Unemployment Rate - Job Losers",
        "U3: Unemployment Rate",
        "U4: All of U3, plus discouraged workers",
        "U5: All of U4, plus marginally attached workers",
        "U6: All of U5, plus total employed part time for economic reasons"
    )),
    col = rev(pal[1:6]),
    bty = 'n',
    lty = 1
)

dev.copy(svg, "US Unemployment measures.svg", width=8, height=6)
dev.off()
```

Despite it's the unmodified source code form Wikimedia Commons, the lines are all bogus:

[image: PNG]

What's wrong with the R script?

Is it because u1-u6 are falsely being interpreted as factors?

Comment: If you're unsure about the structure of your data, call `str` on it to see if those are indeed factors or characters

Comment: Those first two lines are some of the most misleading lines I've seen in a script in a while.

Comment: In case you didn't understand @Dason comment, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6150337/2761575

Comment: @Dason The code I've copied started only with "if (F) {", so I've had to invent something. But it's indeed very funny.

Comment: @LuisPaganini To be blunt - nobody here cares about the code you copied. We care about the code you put here.  If you want that code block to be run for your example then you don't need to have those two lines at all and should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Just glancing at the raw data, there's an issue with your code:

```
u$time <- u$year + (as.numeric(u$period) - 1) / 12
```

But the period column has values like 'M01', 'M02', 'Q01', Q02'.  Since that column contains characters, `read.table` converts it to factors by default (you can turn that off).  Calling `as.numeric` on something like 'M01' will just return the numerical, ordinal value of the factor.

Comment: And how to fix this (if you would be so kind)? I never use R.

Comment: Something like: `u$time <- u$year + (as.numeric(substr(u$period, 2,3))-1) / 12`

Comment: But that assumes all values in the `period` column are in the format I noted above.