# Sudden change of class from "matrix" to "integer"

Tags: r, matrix

Apparently some matrices when indexed in a certain way stay matrices, others, indexed **in the same way**  become arrays. Example:

```
> test = matrix(1:10, nrow = 2)
> class(test)
[1] "matrix"
> class(test[,1:2])
[1] "matrix"
> test = matrix(1:10, nrow = 1)
> class(test)
[1] "matrix"
> class(test[,1:2])
[1] "integer"
```

I would like to know:

1. Why is this a feature and not a bug?
2. Is there a polished way to make it stay a matrix? (I mean, sure, I could store `nrow(test)` somewhere and then use `matrix(test, nrow = somewhere)`) but i hope that there's a neat one-liner for something that in principle should have worked authomatically.

P.S. Why I find this an issue? Because if I then transpose the vector with `t()` (the vector that lost the matrix structure) it gives me a row vector, I wanted a column vector, as it should have been in theory. Also, `rowMeans()` doesn't work anymore with that vector.

Comment: Yes, when `[` applied to a matrix gets a single row or column back, the extra dimensions are silently "dropped" and it becomes a vector. This can be disabled by using the `drop = FALSE` argument. `class(test[, 1:2, drop = FALSE])`.

Comment: Regarding 1: it *is* widely considered a bug (or at least a mistake), which is why e.g. ‘tibble’ explicitly breaks inheritance rules to change this behaviour in the `tibble` class which inherits from `data.frame`.

Comment: This is also one of the top answers  in the old FAQ about [the biggest R "gotchas"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1535231/903061)